# RFID reader connected to NodeMCU via RS485 - Not Working

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, rs485

I want to connect a long range RFID card reader unit to NodeMCU (12E) board and read the card number. The RFID reader board has a RS485 output port and when I connect this board to my laptop using a RS485 to USB converter, I get the card number using a RealTerm/CoolTerm program.

I was just wondering how I can directly connect the RFID reader board to NodeMCU and read the card number.

I did the following so far, any help in this regard will be much appreciated -

1. Connected RFID board with a RS485 to USB converter
2. Used a female to female USB connector and connected (1) with NodeMCU at the other end(via micro usb port on NodeMCU)
3. Written a very simple arduino sketch to read the serial data as -

   ```
   #define BUZZER 4

   void setup() {

     Serial.begin(9600);      // Init Serial
   }

   void loop(){

   if (Serial.available())
     { 
         tone(BUZZER, 5000);
         delay(1000);
         noTone(BUZZER);
     }
   }
   ```

However, the buzzer gives no sound.

My questions are -

1. Is this the right way of reading data from the card reader via RS485 port ?
2. Why the data is not received in NodeMCU while I can see it on the terminal program on my laptop
3. Is there any arduino sketch that I can refer to to read the card number in NodeMCU ?

Comment: You can't just use a female to female USB connector and expect this to work. USB doesn't work that way. One device needs to be a host and neither of those is one.

Comment: Thanks!  Was wondering if I can use RS485 to TTL converter and connect to NodeMCU to get the data?

Comment: With the right converter it should be possible.